# Remove popup keyboard from MDDataTable KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am currently busy with a basic GUI for a small project I'm working on. The GUI is written in python using kivy. I have written all my code in the .py file and don't have any additional .kv files.

My issue is as follows; when I select or simply just click on the datatable the keyboard pops up.

I don't want this to happen unless the user specifically clicks on a textarea.

Any help would be appreciated.

Attached below is a snippet which illustrates the issue I am having.

```
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp

width, height = 800, 479
Window.size = width, height


class Products(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Products, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        data_table = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.32},
                                 size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
                                 check=True,
                                 rows_num=10,
                                 column_data=[
                                     ("Name", 0.05 * width),
                                     ("Unit", 0.01 * width),
                                     ("Density", 0.03 * width),
                                     ("Calibration Factor", 0.05 * width),
                                     ("Required Rate", 0.03 * width),
                                 ],
                                 row_data=[
                                     ("Fynsaad", "kg", "0.0158", "0.0034", "5.5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                     ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                                 ]
                                 )

        self.add_widget(data_table)


class Xocto(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Products(name="Products"))
        return sm

Xocto().run()
```

Comment: Can you provide a smaller example, this code is not readable...

Comment: Your application is not responsive, on my screen all widgets are stuck together or overlaid

Comment: Hi @Neizvestnyj I've edited the original post to an example that's a bit shorter. Thanks

Comment: Is your issue related to android?

Comment: Everything works well on the PC

Comment: No, the issue isn't related to Android, I'm currently working on Windows and Raspberry pi OS. Everything works, I just don't want the keyboard to popup when the table is clicked. I only want the keyboard to appear for textarea inputs. Thanks.

Comment: Everything works correctly. There is no text field in your example

Comment: What do you mean by everything works correctly, does the virtual keyboard not pop up when clicking on the table or on the checkbox? What version of Kivy or KivyMD are you running? Is your keyboard docked?

Comment: `kivy==2.0.0`, `kivymd==master`, the keyboard doesn't open